# Using a try catch statement to check that one object equals another

Tags: java, try-catch

I'm working on a program; there is a truck class, a vehicle class, a person class, and a driver class.

The truck and vehicle are used to set information to the vehicles and the person is used to set the person information, and the driver runs it all.

My current issue is I am trying to use a try catch statement to check that the user is entering data that is the same as they entered for the previous but cant seem to get it right.

I will attach all my classes below, it's lengthy but hopefully helps.

```
//driver class

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;

public class Driver{

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);
        //creates vehicles
        Vehicle car1= new Vehicle();
        Vehicle car2= new Vehicle();
        Vehicle car3= new Vehicle();

        //creates trucks
        Truck truck1= new Truck();
        Truck truck2= new Truck();
        Truck truck3= new Truck();

        boolean check1=true;
        boolean check2=true;
        boolean check3=true;
        boolean nameCheck=false;
        boolean truckCheck1=false;
        boolean truckCheck2=false;
        boolean truckCheck3=false;

        while(!nameCheck) {

            System.out.println("Enter first persons name");

            Person owner1 = new Person(keyboard.next()); // creates new person
            car1.setOwner(owner1); //makes the first person the owner of the first car
            if (car1.equals(car1)) //checking if name is null
                nameCheck=true;

        }

        System.out.println("You entered: " + car1.getOwner()); //echoes user input
        System.out.println("Enter manufacturer of car 1");
        car1.setManufacturer(keyboard.next()); //set manufacturer of car 1
        System.out.println("You entered: " + car1.getManufacturer() + " as car 1 manufacturer");

        while( check1 && nameCheck){
            try //data check
            {
                System.out.println("Enter number of cylinders for car 1");
                car1.setCylinders(keyboard.nextInt());

                if (car1.cylinders<2 || car1.cylinders>30)
                    throw new Exception("You entered an invalid amount of cylidners!");

                else
                    check1=false;
                System.out.println(car1.toString());
            }

            catch (InputMismatchException e){
                keyboard.next();
                System.out.println("Cylinders must be entered in integer form");
                System.out.println("Try again!");
            }

            catch (Exception e){
                String message = e.getMessage();
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        }


        while (!check1){
            System.out.println("Please set name, car manufacturer, and cylinders equal to car 1");

        try{
            System.out.println("Enter second persons name");
            Person owner2 = new Person (keyboard.next());
            car2.setOwner(owner2);

            if (!car2.getOwner().equals(car1.getOwner()))
                throw new Exception("Invalid name entered, please enter same name as owner 1");

                else
                check1=true;
            }

        catch(Exception e){
            keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter same owner as car 1");
            System.out.println("Try again!");
        }

            System.out.println("You entered: " + car2.getOwner());
            check1=true;

            System.out.println("Enter manufacturer of car 2");
            car2.setManufacturer(keyboard.next());
            System.out.println("You entered: " + car2.getManufacturer());

            while (nameCheck) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Enter number of cylinders for the second vehicle");
                    car2.setCylinders(keyboard.nextInt());
                    if (car2.cylinders< 2 || car2.cylinders>30)
                        throw new Exception("You entered an invalid amount of cylinders!");

                        else
                            check2= false;

                            System.out.println(car2.toString());
                        }
                        catch(InputMismatchException e) {
                            keyboard.next();
                            System.out.println("Cylinders must be entered a as an integer between 2 and 30");
                            System.out.println("Try again!");
                        } catch (Exception e){

                            String message= e.getMessage();
                            System.out.println(message);
                        }
                    }
                }

                while (!check2) {
                    System.out.println("Enter third persons name");
                    Person owner3= new Person(keyboard.next());
                    car3.setOwner(owner3);
                    System.out.println("You entered: " + owner3);

                    System.out.println("Enter manufacturer of car 3");
                    car3.setManufacturer(keyboard.next());
                    System.out.println("You entered: " + car3.getManufacturer());
                    while (check3) {
                        try {
                            System.out.println("Enter number of cylinders for car 3");
                            car3.setCylinders(keyboard.nextInt());

                            if (car3.cylinders<2 || car3.cylinders>30)

                                throw new Exception("Invalid amount of cylinder entered!");

                                else
                                    check2=true;
                                    check3=false;
                                    check1=false;
                                    System.out.println(car3.toString());
                                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {

                                    keyboard.next();
                                    System.out.println("Cylinders must be entered a as an integer between 2 and 30");
                                    System.out.println("Try again!");
                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                    String message= e.getMessage();
                                    System.out.println(message);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        truck1.setOwner(car1.getOwner()); //sets owner of car1 to truck1
                        System.out.println("Enter manufacturer of truck 1, Owner will be the same as car 1");
                        truck1.setManufacturer(keyboard.next());

                        System.out.println("You entered: " + truck1.getManufacturer());
                        while (!truckCheck1)
                            try {
                                System.out.println("Enter cyliners for truck 1");

                                truck1.setCylinders(keyboard.nextInt());
                                if (truck1.cylinders<2 || truck1.cylinders>30)

                                    throw new Exception("Invalid amount of cylinders entered!");

                                else
                                    truckCheck1= true;
                                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {

                                    keyboard.nextInt();
                                    System.out.println("Cylinders must be entered a as an integer between 2 and 30");
                                    System.out.println("Try again!");
                                } catch (Exception e) {

                                    String message= e.getMessage();
                                    System.out.println(message);
                                }
                            System.out.println("You entered: " + truck1.getCylinders());
                            while (truckCheck1)
                                try {
                                    System.out.println("Enter load capacity in tons for truck 1. Must be greater than zero");
                                    truck1.setLoadCapacity(keyboard.nextDouble());
                                    if (truck1.getLoadCapacity()<0)

                                        throw new Exception("You entered an invalid load capacity");

                                    else
                                        truckCheck1= false;
                                    } catch(InputMismatchException e) {

                                        keyboard.next();
                                        System.out.println("Load capacity must be in integer format");
                                        System.out.println("Try again!");
                                    } catch (Exception e) {

                                        String message= e.getMessage();
                                        System.out.println(message);
                                    }

                                    System.out.println("You entered: " + truck1.getLoadCapacity());

                                    while (!truckCheck1)
                                        try {

                                            System.out.println("Enter towing capacity in pounds of truck 1");

                                            truck1.setTowCapacity(keyboard.nextInt());
                                            if (truck1.getTowCapacity()<0)

                                                throw new Exception("You entered an invalid tow capacity, tow capacity must be entered as an integer");

                                            else
                                                truckCheck1= true;
                                            }catch (InputMismatchException e){

                                                keyboard.next();
                                                System.out.println("Towing Capacity must be in integer form");
                                                System.out.println("Try again!");

                                            } catch (Exception e){

                                                String message= e.getMessage();
                                                System.out.println(message);
                                            }
                                            System.out.println(truck1);

                                            truck2.setOwner(car2.getOwner()); //sets truck 2 owner the same as car 2 owner
                                            System.out.println("Enter manufacturer of truck 2");
                                            truck2.setManufacturer(keyboard.next());
                                            System.out.println("You entered: " + truck2.getManufacturer());

                                            while(!truckCheck2)
                                                try {
                                                    System.out.println("Enter number of cylinders for truck 2, must be a integer between 2 and 30");

                                                    truck2.setCylinders(keyboard.nextInt());
                                                    if (truck2.cylinders<2 || truck2.cylinders>30)

                                                        throw new Exception("You entered an invalid amount of cylinders");

                                                    else
                                                        truckCheck2= true;
                                                    } catch (InputMismatchException e){

                                                    keyboard.next();
                                                    System.out.println("Load capacity must be entered as an integer");
                                                    System.out.println("Try again!");
                                            } catch (Exception e){

                                                    String message= e.getMessage();
                                                    System.out.println(message);
                                                }

                                            System.out.println("You entered: " + truck2.getCylinders());

                                            while (truckCheck2)
                                                try{

                                                    System.out.println("Enter towing capacity in pounds of truck 2");
                                                    truck2.setLoadCapacity(keyboard.nextDouble());
                                                    if (truck2.getLoadCapacity()<0)

                                                        throw new Exception("Invalid Tow Capacity Entered");

                                                    else
                                                        truckCheck2=false;
                                                    }catch (InputMismatchException e){

                                                        keyboard.next();
                                                        System.out.println("Load Capacity must be entered as an integer");
                                                        System.out.println("Try again!");
                                                    } catch (Exception e) {

                                                        String message = e.getMessage();
                                                        System.out.println(message);
                                                    }
                                                System.out.println("You entered: " + truck1.getLoadCapacity());

                                                while (!truckCheck2)
                                                    try {

                                                        System.out.println("Enter Towing capacity in pounds of truck 1");

                                                        truck2.setTowCapacity(keyboard.nextInt());
                                                        if (truck2.getTowCapacity()<0)

                                                            throw new Exception("Invalid Tow Capacity Entered");

                                                        else
                                                            truckCheck2= true;
                                                        } catch (InputMismatchException e){

                                                            keyboard.next();
                                                            System.out.println("Towing Capacity must be entered as an integer");
                                                            System.out.println("Try again!");
                                                        } catch (Exception e){

                                                            String message= e.getMessage();
                                                            System.out.println(message);
                                                        }
                                                    System.out.println(truck2);

                                //collectin third truck info
                                truck3.setOwner(car3.getOwner());

                                System.out.println("Enter manufacturer of truck 3, Owner will be the same as car 3");
                                truck3.setManufacturer(keyboard.next());
                                System.out.println("You entered: " + truck3.getManufacturer());

                                while(!truckCheck3)
                                    try{
                                        System.out.println("Enter Cylinders of truck 3, must be a integet between 2 and 30");

                                        truck3.setCylinders(keyboard.nextInt());
                                        if(truck3.cylinders<2 || truck3.cylinders>30)

                                            throw new Exception("Invalid amount of cylinders entered");

                                        else
                                            truckCheck3= true;
                                    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {

                                        keyboard.next();
                                        System.out.println("Cylinders must be an integer");
                                        System.out.println("Try again!");
                                    } catch (Exception e){

                                        String message= e.getMessage();
                                        System.out.println(message);
                                    }

                                System.out.println("You entered: " + truck3.getCylinders());

                                while (truckCheck3)
                                    try {
                                        System.out.println("Enter load capacity in tons of truck 3, must be greater than 0");
                                        truck3.setLoadCapacity(keyboard.nextDouble());
                                        if (truck3.getLoadCapacity()<0)

                                            throw new Exception("Invalid amount entered");

                                        else
                                            truckCheck3= false;
                                        } catch (InputMismatchException e){

                                            keyboard.next();
                                            System.out.println("Load capacity must be in integer form");
                                            System.out.println("Try again!");
                                        } catch (Exception e) {

                                            String message= e.getMessage();
                                            System.out.println(message);
                                        }
                                    System.out.println("You entered: " + truck3.getLoadCapacity());

                                    while(!truckCheck3)
                                        try {

                                            System.out.println("Enter towing capacity in pounds of truck 3");

                                            truck3.setTowCapacity(keyboard.nextInt());
                                            if (truck3.getTowCapacity()<0)

                                                throw new Exception("Invalud amount entered");

                                            else
                                                truckCheck3= true;
                                        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {

                                            keyboard.next();
                                            System.out.println("Towing capacity must be in integer form");
                                            System.out.println("Try again!");
                                        } catch (Exception e) {

                                            String message= e.getMessage();
                                            System.out.println(message);
                                        }

                                    System.out.println();
                                    System.out.println("Car Details:" + "\n" + "Car 1:" + car1 + "\n" + "Car 2:" + "\n" + car2 + "\n" + "Car 3:" + "\n" + car3);
                                    System.out.println();
                                    System.out.println("Truck Details:" + "\n" + "Truck 1:" + truck1 + "\n" + "Truck 2:" + "\n" + truck2 + "\n" + "Truck 3:" + "\n" + truck3);
                        }
                    }

    /** vehicle class
    Carmine  */

    public class Vehicle{

    public String manufacturer;
    public int cylinders;
    public Person owner; //owner pulled from person class

    public Vehicle(){
        manufacturer="none";
        cylinders=1;
        owner=null;
    }

    public Vehicle(String theManufacturer, int numOfCylinders, Person theOwner)
    {
        theManufacturer=manufacturer;
        numOfCylinders=cylinders;
        owner=new Person(theOwner);
    }

    //sets manufacturer
    public void setManufacturer(String newManufacturer){
        manufacturer=newManufacturer;
    }

    //return manufacturer name
    public String getManufacturer(){
        return manufacturer;
    }

    //sets cylinders
    public void setCylinders(int numOfCylinders){
        cylinders=numOfCylinders;
    }

    //return cylinders
    public int getCylinders(){
        return cylinders;
    }

    //sets owner
    public void setOwner(Person newOwner)
    {
    owner = new Person(newOwner);
    }

    //returns owner
    public Person getOwner(){
        return owner;
    }

    @Override
        public String toString(){
        return ("Manufaturer: " + manufacturer + "\n" + "Cylinders: " + cylinders + "\n" + "Owner: " + owner);
    }
    }

    //Person Class
    public class Person {
    private String name;

    public Person()

    {
        name = "none";
    }

    public Person(String theName) {
        name = theName;
    }

    public Person(Person theObject) {
        name = theObject.name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String theName) {
        name = theName;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return name.equals(((Person) other).name);

    }
    }

    public class Truck extends Vehicle //entends truck from vehicle
    {
    double loadCapacity;
    int towCapacity;

    public Truck(){
        super();
        loadCapacity=0;
        towCapacity=0;
    }

    public Truck(String m, int c, Person p, double load, int capacity){
        super(m,c,p);
        loadCapacity=load;
        towCapacity=capacity;
    }

    //sets load
    public void setLoadCapacity(double newLoad){
        loadCapacity=newLoad;
    }

    //returns load
    public double getLoadCapacity(){
        return loadCapacity;
    }

    //sets towCapacity
    public void setTowCapacity(int newCapacity){
        towCapacity=newCapacity;
    }

    //return towCapacity
    public int getTowCapacity(){
        return towCapacity;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return super.toString() + ("Load Capacity: " + loadCapacity + "\n" + "Tow Capacity: " + towCapacity);
    }
}
```

I know its a lot of code but this try catch statement is really holding me up and I just want to finish this.

Also I need to use `.equals` to check there equal, in this; two people need to be the same as well as two trucks and cars.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is throwing an `Exception` when your check fails, not an `InputMismatchException`. So your output to "try again" is not printed.

I'm a little puzzled about using the exceptions in the first place. Why not just handle the problem right in the `if` block when you know that there's a problem, since it's all contained within the `while` loop until the input is correct?

Exceptions are normally used in very exceptional situations, such as system errors or unexpected events. Most of the time, if you can check the input immediately after getting it from the user, the code can deal with whether or not it's valid right at the point, as it would in your loop.

Comment: im new to try catch statements, dont fully understand them yet, i thought it would work as every time they input incorrect data it would throw the exception but it doesnt which confused me, making the problem be handled in the if statement does make more sense, illl change that

Comment: Yes, there are lots of things in programming like this are confusing, since the usage is often a matter of style. It's definitely possible to make exceptions work in a case like this, but it's more complicated than it needs to be and there are easier ways to do it.